# How can I improve the speed of this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I was using `long.TryParse`, but switched to regex.  Currently, it takes a total of 7+ milliseconds for a 123+K message.  The 7+ milliseconds is from the XElement.Parse to the end of the foreach methods.

```
Stopwatch s1 =Stopwatch.StartNew();
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);    

string pattern = @"\b\d+\b";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = element
    .Descendants()
    .Where(d => d.Attributes()
        .Where(a => a.Value.Length >= 13 &&
               a.Value.Length <= 16 &&
               r.IsMatch(a.Value)).Count() == 1)
    .Select(x => x);

foreach(var x in elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers)
{
    foreach(var a in x.Attributes())
    {
        //Check if the value is a number
        if(r.IsMatch(a.Value))
        {
            //Check if value is the credit card
            if(a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16)
            {
                a.Value = Regex.Replace(a.Value, @"\b\d{13,16}\b", match => 
                    new String('*', match.Value.Length - 4) +
                    match.Value.Substring(match.Value.Length - 4)
                );
        }
        else //If value is not a credit card, replace it with ***
                a.Value = Regex.Replace(a.Value ,@"\b\d+\b", "***");
        }
    }
}

xml = element.ToString();
s1.Stop();
```

`XElement.Parse(xml);` takes between 2 - 3 ms.

The LINQ query takes between 0.004 - 0.005 ms.

The foreach statements take between 4 - 5 ms.

Comment: Really only 7ms? Sounds good to me.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - Yeah for one message its fine, but I have a ton of these coming in, so its the volume of messages.

Comment: Have you tried static compiled regex?

Comment: @MarcGravell - What is that? Do you have an example?  Also Jon Skeet mentioned something about using Nullable for attributes.

Comment: ok, I added the RegexOptions.Compiled, but that made it slower.

Comment: Why bother with parsing as xml when it appears that all you are trying to do is replace some text? Have you tried just doing a regex replace against the raw XML string? Clearly, it might not be an option, but I would guess that you are spending a good part of your time parsing the xml.

Comment: Could you not exit the inner `foreach` loop if you found a CC Number? Assuming there is only going to be 1 CC Number per element?

Comment: It only makes it faster if you declare the regex before you perform the loop! `var regex = new Regex("pattern", RegexOptions.Compiled);`. In the loop `regex.Replace(s, "replacement");`

Comment: @Xaisoft Don't instantiate your RegEx every time if you use `RegexOptions.Compiled`: use a single RegEx instance.

Comment: Dont think this is the bottleneck but cant you change your link query to this ====>       var elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = element.Descendants().Where(d => d.Attributes().Count(a => a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16 && r.IsMatch(a.Value)) == 1);
                                                 One "Where" less

Comment: @Xaisoft: Just how many of these are you meant to process per second? If you have (say) 4 cores processing 142 messages each, then that could be 4 * 142 * 123K ~= 70MB = 560Mbps. If you really need a single machine to process that much data, I'd suggest you have an architecture issue. Try to scale horizontally instead.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Do you not have any idea which elements might contain credit card numbers? Looking through every attribute in the document seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: as in... `static readonly Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);`

Comment: Sounds like overoptimization...

Comment: Even using a naive search thru every attribute you can get 10MB/s (with 10k attributes, 10% match rate).

Comment: @Mark - I can't just replace text because the XML is not standard, it varies from client to client.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Ah, I get you, I was doing it to the first Regex right after the  XElement.Parse method.

Comment: @JonSkeet - We have 3 machines processing the messages.  The amount of messages vary.  Also, I have no idea which elements contain credit cards, I am just basing it of an number between 13 and 16 digits.

Comment: @Xaisoft: It seems very odd, to have so little clue as to the input format. Dangerous, too - as you could end up getting non-credit-card numbers which just *happen* to be 13-16 digits.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Let me explain. I do have the format, but all the clients implement different formats so when a message comes in, there is no way to tell which one it is.  There is no standard.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Then what do you mean by "I do have the format"? It sounds like you're dealing with effectively unstructured data - which, as I say, sounds dangerous. What exactly are you building, anyway? I've never heard of financial data being **legitimately** passed around in such an ad-hoc manner.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The data is structured, but different property management systems (PMS) send the data differently, by differently I mean, some may call the credit card data section `ccinfo` while others may call it `guarantee`.  Also, each PMS could put as little or as many attributes as they want.  The financial data is just a small portion of the XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Now, I have thought about checking which PMS is sending the message and then just getting the credit card node and encrypting it, but that would mean for every new PMS, I would have to change the code, which could be forgotten and be a security risk, so I am trying for a solution that would cover all scenarios.

Comment: @Xaisoft: You should *absolutely* handle each client differently. Taking on a new client system should have a thorough process - it shouldn't just be something you hope works because you've got something which may recognize credit card numbers. There may be other personal information in there which should be taken into account, too - if you don't consult about the incoming information, you're in no position to handle it IMO.

Comment: @Xaisoft: You still haven't said how many of these you're expecting to process. If you really want to handle thousands of requests per second, I would put more than three machines behind it...

Comment: @JonSkeet - I completely agree with you that every client should be handled differently, but some are concerned that someone is going to forget to handle a client and then all data will be exposed.

Comment: @Xaisoft: That's easy: if it's not a format you explicitly recognize, reject it and raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're doing two search and replacements:

1. Replace every CC number with `*`'s and the last 4 digits
2. Replace any other "CC-ish" number *on the same element* with `*`'s.

One approach would be to make XLinq work a little bit harder for you:

```
// you're not using the elements, ignore them, just get the attributes
foreach (var atr in xelt.Descendants()
                        .Where(e => e.Attributes()
                                     .Any(a => a.Value.Length >= 13
                                            && a.Value.Length <= 16))
                        .SelectMany(e => e.Attributes()))
{
    // static basicDigits = new Regex(@"\b\d+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    // static ccDigits = new Regex(@"\b\d{13,16}\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    if (ccDigits.IsMatch(atr.Value))
    {
         atr.Value = ccDigits.Replace(
             atr.Value,
             mm => new String('*', mm.Value.Length - 4)
                   + mm.Value.Substring(mm.Value.Length - 4));
    }
    else
    {
        atr.Value = basicDigits.Replace(atr.Value, "***");
    }
}

// using 150k XML (1k nodes/5k attrs, 3 attr/node avg, avg depth 4 nodes)
// with 10% match rate:
// - 25.7 MB/s (average 100 trials)
// - 61 attributes/ms
```

Sample input XML:

```
<item f1="abc123abc" f2="helloooo 1234567" f3="abc123abc">
     <item f1="abc123abc" f2="helloooo 1234567" f3="abc123abc" real1="4444555566667777" />
     <item f1="abc123abc" f2="helloooo 1234567" f3="abc123abc" />
     ruBTMjSesurMsP6lK2jg
 </item>
```

Output:

```
<item f1="abc123abc" f2="helloooo 1234567" f3="abc123abc">
     <item f1="abc123abc" f2="helloooo ***" f3="abc123abc" real1="************7777" />
     <item f1="abc123abc" f2="helloooo 1234567" f3="abc123abc" />
     ruBTMjSesurMsP6lK2jg
</item>
```

Comment: I'm trying this now.  I thought about just getting the attributes, but wasn't sure how.  I will let you know.

Comment: Ok, I noticed a few things. The time didn't change, it pretty much stayed the same and the credit card number is being replaced, but the other cc-ish numbers are retaining their value.

Comment: Curious, how did you come up with those metrics in your comments below the code?

Comment: I have heard that using XmlReader could be faster?

Comment: I bench marked a couple areas of my program. I will update my post.

Comment: I guess I can't use XmlReader since the XML varies. I read on MSDN that XmlReader is only good if you deal with XML that is the same.

Comment: I see the problem, your query is only returning attributes that have values between 13 and 16 digits.  The XML I am using can contain numerical values that are less than 13 or greater than 16.

Comment: Is there a way to get the all the attributes that are on the same element as the 13-16 digit number.

Comment: Yes, I want to replace all numerical attributes with `***`.  The credit card number will be replaced with `***************1234` for example.  That is what I am doing in my inner foreach statement.

Comment: Note:  all numerical attributes that are on the same element as the credit card number.

Comment: After running several options, it appears that my original query is not that bad.

Comment: It actually started running from 7+ to 2+ ms for 123000K message, but it has an initial high of around 6 ms.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider precompiling your regex. The article here: http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Compiling_Regular_Expressions explains the pro and cons of compiling regex quite nicely.